# XXX is a table without a header line and therefore has no component called "EBELN"

Tags: abap

I'm getting the syntax error:

> "IT_COMBINE" is a table without a header line and therefore has no component called "EBELN".

I have tried using "into corresponding fields" and that does not work.

My code:

```
  19   Data it_combine type standard table of ty_combine.
  ...
  32    select ebeln lifnr ekorg bsart ekgrp
  33      into table it_po
  34       from ekko
  35         where ebeln = it_combine-ebeln. " <=== SYNTAX ERROR
  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use the fields in internal tables directly if you did not declare your internal table with header line.

There are 2 possibilities to change your code.

1. You have called field ebeln in line no 35. Since you did not declare it_combine with header line in line no 19, you can not use it_combine-ebeln like this. Instead you have to declare **Work Area**

   ```
   Data wa_combine type ty_combine.
   ```

and use the work area in line no 35 as

```
Loop at it_combine into wa_combine .
 select ebeln lifnr ekorg bsart ekgrp
   into table it_po
    from ekko
      where ebeln = wa_combine-ebeln.
End Loop.
```

2 You have to declare your internal table with header line

```
 Data it_combine type standard table of ty_combine with header line.
```

Refer to the Sap help document for breif description about header line and work area.

Comment: SAP recommends against using header lines.  The loop part of your answer would work, but rather than suggesting a header line, a for all entries select would make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the addition "FOR ALL ENTRIES IN" for statement "SELECT":

```
SELECT DISTINCT ebeln netwr werks INTO TABLE it_combine
  FROM ekpo
  WHERE netwr IN s_netwr. "in is only for select options

  CHECK it_combine[] IS NOT INITIAL. " not empty, obligatory

 SELECT ebeln lifnr ekorg bsart ekgrp
  INTO TABLE it_po  
  FROM ekko FOR ALL ENTRIES IN it_combine
  WHERE ebeln = it_combine-ebeln.
```

"with header line" or additional work area - not need

Also, using "with header line" impossible in the OOP context.

Comment: Worth mentioning that FOR ALL ENTRIES IN x is a not-cool addition, and it should be used only when x is a rather small itab (regarding the row count). Of course, it's good that you mentioned it.

Comment: I'd change the first select to:

`SELECT ebeln netwr werks INTO TABLE it_combine
  FROM ekpo
  WHERE netwr IN s_netwr.

SORT it_combine.

DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM it_combine COMPARING ALL FIELDS.`


to leave removing duplicates to ABAP, not the DB engine.