# Pick field value from an ABAP structure

Tags: abap

I'm trying to pick up the value from a field which is in a table line. But I cannot access it because my table has no header line.
I have the following code:

```
DATA: t2            TYPE TABLE OF komlfp,
      go_settlement TYPE REF TO cl_wb2_rebate_settlement_2.
TRY.

  CREATE OBJECT go_settlement.

  go_settlement->settlement(
                   EXPORTING
                     iv_testrun        = 'X'
                     iv_bldat          = sy-datum
                     iv_wfdat          = sy-datum
                     is_contract       = wa_view
                     is_contract_first = wa_view
                   IMPORTING
                     et_komlfk         = t1
                     et_komlfp         = t2 ).

CATCH cx_wb2_rebates.
ENDTRY.
```

What I want now is to use the value **t2-kzwi6d**, but I always get:

> "T2" is a table without a header line and therefore does not have a component
>   called "KZWI6D".

I've already tried declaring the table with a header line, but when I try that, I get:

> Tables with headers are no longer supported in the OO context.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "IT\_COMBINE" is a table without a header line and therefore has no component called "EBELN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874121/error-it-combine-is-a-table-without-a-header-line-and-therefore-has-no-compone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created t2 as a table without a header line, so the program cannot recognize any column names.

One solution could be to define it as a table with a header line, though that approach is considered obsolete and outdated.

```
DATA: t2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF komlfp WITH HEADER LINE.
```

Another option is to dynamically get the field value. But then you have to make sure it actually exists and that the assign worked, so more error management is necessary.

```
DATA: t2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF komlfp.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <t2_line> LIKE LINE OF t2,
               <kzwi6d>  TYPE kzwi6.

LOOP AT t2 ASSIGNING <t2_line>.
  ASSIGN COMPONENT 'KZWI6D' OF STRUCTURE <t2_line> TO <kzwi6d>.
ENDLOOP.
```

Edit: As Sandra has pointed out, **you don't have to do it dynamically and can just get the value directly like this as well**:

```
DATA: t2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF komlfp.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <t2_line> LIKE LINE OF t2.

LOOP AT t2 ASSIGNING <t2_line>.
  " you now have access to the value using <t2_line>-kzwi6d
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: `ASSIGN` is not needed because the type of t2 is declared and complete (not generic). Instead, just use `<t2_line>-kzwi6d`.

Comment: You declared t2 "WITH HEADER LINE" don't need to do LOOP AT... ASSIGNING ...

Comment: Ah, that was a copypaste mistake, thanks for pointing it out.